# config TFS 2010 beta 2 on local network with ssl

Tags: team-foundation-server

in this case i can only use self signed certificates. i can only generate the certs with the computer name or IP. what do I need to do so that the local clients will recognize the cert?

Answer (score 1):

afaik, unless you use a commercial cert or setup your own internal ca, you'll need to manually install the cert into the cert store on each client.